# While uploading the img file src in img tag not working (src url not changing)

Tags: html, jquery, laravel

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 pl-md-1">
<label class="ORGAd16-preview">
input type='file' name="modelvariant_file" id="imageUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" >
<img id="imagePreview"    src="<?php echo url('/') ?>/public/assets/images/upload-profile.png">
</label>
```

when I upload the image. i can able to select image but image is  not showing after uploading . same time img tag src attribute remains same not changing.is this information enough ? or need more

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ignore the closing tag at `'` at the `url('/')` try using `src="<?php echo url(\'/\') ?>/public/assets/images/upload-profile.png"` which will ignore the closing tag